# C++ std::cin and std::cout result in segmentation faults

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, std

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    std::string s;

    std::cin >> s;
    return 0;
}
```

Build with:
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\myUser\Dokumente\codes\C++\hello_world.cpp -o C:\Users\myUser\Dokumente\codes\C++\hello_world.exe

results in (line 8):
Exception has occurred.
Segmentation fault

Should be:
Should output Hello, World to the console.

why does it not do that?
do i need to use vsc in admin mode?

Comment: Are you sure you saved your file? VSCode is notorious for not saving files with little visual notification about that.

Comment: yes, autosave was enabled before i wrote this code :)

Comment: The code as posted works for me. Just as an aside, don't use `using namespace std;`, especially since you are using (correctly) `std::cout` and `std::cin`.

Comment: Does it work if you compile and run inside of MSYS2 shell? There might be some conflicting DLLs in PATH in VSC, and MSYS2 uses its own clean PATH in its shell.

Comment: This sounds like an installation problem--there's nothing obviously wrong with the code, and it works fine for me, compiled with either Microsoft's compiler and/or [STL's MINGW port](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html).

Comment: I'd double-check that you're indeed compiling and running the program you think you do. Create a new project in a completely separate directory with a completely different name, copy your code _from the question_ there, open the folder in Explorer, hit "compile" exactly once, watch the `.exe` file appear, run it exactly once.

Comment: Hello everyone, it seems that it was an installation problem. A reinstallation would help, but then also i had to uninstall Neovim because it had the stdc++ library in its binary-folder and my system was configured to use that (by an unsuspecting me or some developer that made neovim). 
if someone of you would like to have the accepted answer, id gladly accept one. until then